# Restoring files and folders from Deja Dup backup

Tags: kubuntu, backup, restore, deja-dup, duplicity

I had hoped restoring files and folders backed up with Deja Dup would be a straight forward process but unfortunately this is not the case.

This is my predicament: a week ago I foolishly decided to update kubuntu from version 17.10 to 18.04 and after the 2400+ files had been downloaded I let the program take care of itself and called it a night, excepting the upgrade to have executed without any issues. Instead, the upgrade had stalled within half an hour of me turning out the lights and was frozen stiff in the morning. There was nothing to do but reboot, after which everything went pear shaped.

In the end I resorted to a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 from a bootable USB, confident that all my files had been backed up only days previously. I now have a fully functional kubuntu desktop but have hit a brick wall as how to restore some 250 GB of blockchain data and sundry other files.

My strategy was to simply decompress all the backed up files and folders in a holding folder on my backup hard-drive and then copy the folders I wanted back to my computer.

I've searched the Duplicity wiki and Deja Dup documentation but haven't found any straight forward answers; nor did I have any luck using the Deja Dup GUI.

I've used variations of this command line to access the backup files but to no avail.

```
snerx@snerx:~$ duplicity restore --no-encryption --file-to-restore /media/snerx/Seagate_Expansion_Drive/Ubuntu_16.04_Backup/*.* file:///media/snerx/Seagate_Expansion_Drive/Holding_folder/
    Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 1
    Enter 'duplicity --help' for help screen.
```

Anyone who may care to suggest a command line to decompress and decrypt my backups to the Holding_folder?

Comment: How about using the gui and "restore to another location" option?

Comment: I would if I could but that option is not available. Are there additional drivers or addons needed to get Deja Dup working to its full potential?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I finally figured out the command line needed to decrypt and decompress the backup files into the Holding folder in the Seagate expansion drive.

```
snerx@snerx:~$ duplicity restore --no-encryption --no-compression file:///media/snerx/Seagate_Expansion_Drive/Ubuntu_16.04_Backup/ /media/snerx/Seagate_Expansion_Drive/Holding_folder/
Local and Remote metadata are synchronised, no sync needed.                                                                                                                                                                     
Last full backup date: Mon Jun  4 00:21:18 2018
```

That restored 320GB of files to the Holding_folder, which could then be copied over to the home folder using Midnight Commander.